# Require Google password on Chrome start-up

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, google-accounts

Is there a way to require Google Chrome to ask for Google Account password on first use/login (on home computer)? I would like to keep the "sync" functionality, but would like to protect the Google Account, and access to sites like Gmail, with an account password for the first session after Windows login.

I'm on Chrome *Version 106.0.5249.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)*, and Windows 11 Home *Version  10.0.22621 Build 22621*, and Windows is protected with a pin code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this (without adding extra password) is to clear the cookies when closing google chrome which forces to login at next session.

Go in *Settings* > *Privacy and security* > *Cookies and other site data*

Tick on *Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows*.

Be aware that you will lose your cookies.